# Schedule using time in tkinter

Tags: python, date, tkinter, time, schedule

I am very new to tkinter and I need some help coding it. So, I am trying to code a type of schedule in tkinter where if the current day is a specified day (for example, Sunday) and if the current time on that day is in between 2 times, then a messagebox pops up. For example, if it is Monday and the current time is in between 11:30 and 12:00, then a message box saying, "Eat lunch!" pops up.

I have been able to code an incomplete version of this on python, but I don't know how to add the current day part and the in between 2 times part and how to apply this to tkinter.

Comment: Hey there, I would like you to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and go through [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and make the necessary changes. Its always a good practice to show your research and work so far related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library. I think it will suit your needs: https://pypi.org/project/schedule/

You can code things like:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```